# Identity Server: Error parsing discovery document

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, webapi

I'm using Identity server 4, locally everything running fine exactly as expected when published the scenario is like the following:

1. Client app is redirected successfully to  the identity server login
   page
2. login process is completed successfully and redirected back to the client app

but the issue is that any request sent to the API is 'unauthorized', by checking the identity server log

> MessageTemplate: "Error parsing discovery document from https://identity-url: Error connecting to https://identity-url.well-known/openid-configuration. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.."
> Exception: "System.InvalidOperationException: Error parsing discovery document from https://identity-url: Error connecting to https://identity-url/.well-known/openid-configuration. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.. at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.GetIntrospectionEndpointFromDiscoveryDocument(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions options) at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.InitializeIntrospectionClient(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions options) at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler.LoadClaimsForToken(String token) at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()"

any advice on what may cause such an issue?

Comment: That suggests that the API application does not have line-of-sight to the identity service. Are you able to remote onto the server/container/whatever and verify connectivity?

Comment: @mackie yes, actually API and Identity server are two sites on the same server and the same IIS

Comment: just because they are on the same IIS, does not mean that the other service is reachable  from within the other service. Both DNS and HTTPS that can give you trouble here depending on your setup.